Meaning of "box to box"
Can you quote the meaning of "box to box" in the OED? The OED is paywalled, so I can't access it.

One of the hardest positions to master is the box-to-box midfield
role because you have to be competent in defence and attack.


What makes you think a specialized sports term is in the OED? This isn't really a phrase used outside of football, so I wouldn't expect an entry in ordinary dictionaries.

I’m voting to close this question because it is asking us to violate the terms and conditions of another website.

@Chenmunka What website? Hasn't everyone given a link?


Focus on another midfielder profile: The box-to-box .
A term from English [UK football] meaning “From zone to zone”, the
box-to-box is a player with a hybrid profile, neither strictly
defensive nor strictly offensive. He must be present when recovering
the ball but also be able to pierce the opposing lines to bring up the
block. The box-to-box work is therefore spread over both surfaces,
hence the importance for players in this position to be complete, both
defensively and offensively, but also above average at the level.
[sic] athletic, including strong endurance and an ability to resist
enemy contact.
Jugglepro

It's refers to a player's skill: from one goal box to the other goal box as defense or offense

Thanks a lot for the explanation

Shakila, you need to google things like: box-to-box + football + UK

Before posting a question, I first did a search, but the OED needs an access for payment. So I can't see the meaning.

Not everything like this would even be in the OED.

M+W sense 3c for box
gives the meaning penalty box.  Although the link leads to a definition  for a different type of penalty box, that of ice hockey rinks, the second example sentence talks about the football field penalty box.

The nightmares of Euro 2024 returned when Giovanni Di Lorenzo surrendered possession close to the Italian penalty box.

The box-to-box midfield role refers to the role such a midfielder has to cover and take responsibility for, from one penalty box to the other one.
Edit
Collins Dictionary sense 3 gives this definition for
box:

singular noun
In football, the box is the penalty area of the field.

box

The inclusion of that example under the linked definition seems like an error - the definition is specifically about where penalized ice hockey players sit, which is certainly not what's being referred to in the context of a football game. A football pitch does have a box-shaped penalty area on the field which can be referred to as a penalty box, but it's unrelated to the off-ice penalty box in a hockey game. The example on the linked page is relevant, but not the definition it's supposed to be an example of.

Thanks, @Nuclear Hoagie.  I'm aware of the definition given in the penalty box link but believe that it should apply to the type on the football field.  I've just added the link to Collins Dictionary.   It defines it as that for a football field.

@NuclearHoagie What is a Box-to-Box midfielder? - Football tactics explained  Read another definition. This is about football (soccer) and Shakila's questions are always about football. https://www.sportskeeda.com/football/what-is-a-box-to-box-midfielder-football-tactics-explained

What happend here? The original comment from Nuclear Hoagie was under the question and now it's here? How did that happen?//penalty box is irrelevant here, really.
